# PostgreSQL timestamp with timezone apply offset when reading

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

First of all I know there are a lot threads about this and I could use the solutions there, f.e. write a python function which converts datetime object to the timezone I need and add this as a filter to jinja2.

But I wanted to skip this step.

Usually PostgreSQL saves datetime objects in `UTC`.

What I did is: I changed the default timezone which postgreSQL uses to save datetime objects to: `Europe/Berlin`

```
ALTER DATABASE postgres SET timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin';
```

This worked, `SHOW timezone;` tells me its `Europe/Berlin`.

But what Postgres does, it still saves the datetime as UTC, but with a +1 offset for Europe/Berlin, which is actually not a problem.

I assumed that when reading the datetime object, Postgres would apply the offset and return the Europe/Berlin time, but it doesn't. It still returns the UTC time, so whats the point in changing the timezone?

I still need to write this filter and manually convert it.

I think there should be a simple way to apply the offset on DB level, or am I wrong?

**EDIT**

Some information, which might help, the model:

```
class User(UserMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    date_added = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
```

How it looks in the DB:

[image]

And here is an example how I load it in jinja2/html:

```
{{ tenant.date_added.strftime('%d.%m.%Y um %H:%M Uhr') }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are right to handle this completely inside the database. When dealing with time zones, **either** use `timestamp with time zone` throughout and let the database handle conversions and such, **or** use `timestamp without time zone` throughout, store UTC timestamps and let the application deal with time zone handling. Mixing these two is usually not a good idea.

PostgreSQL internally stores a `timestamp with time zone` as a timestamp in UTC. Upon conversion to a string , e.g. when data are sent to the client, the data is converted to the *session time zone*, which is configured by the `timezone` parameter.

Setting `timezone` with `ALTER DATABASE` will change the setting *for all future sessions*, that is, you have to disconnect and reconnect for the new setting to take effect.

However, every session is free (and encouraged) to change `timezone` using the `SET` command or the `set_config` function, and this determines to which time zone the timestamps will be converted. Use `SHOW timezone` to see your current setting.

If you store a timestamp without an explicit time zone (like `2019-02-01 12:00:00`), it will be interpreted in your current session time zone. So if that is `Europe/Berlin`, the UTC timestamp stored internally will be `2019-02-01 11:00:00 UTC`. Now if you `SELECT` the value, it will be displayed as `2019-02-01 12:00:00+01`, because that is your current time zone offset. If you change `timezone`, the same value will be displayed differently.

Comment: I have timestamp with time zone, and the DB timezone is Europe/Berlin, so it should return Europe/Berlin on default. I will try to restart the DB. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thats a problem now. I use heroku postgres and its not possible to restart a DB. Is there an other way?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "database time zone". There only is a session time zone. You don't have to restart the database, only disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: Super weird things happening here. It has shown the correct time. I open the site in incognito mode and it shows again UTC time, switch back to non-incognito (where the time was Europe) it is UTC again.

Comment: Your explanation is on point. I think the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Using this at app start `db_session.execute("SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin';")` doesn't influence session settings. It still shows UTC times.

Comment: It would have to be `SET timezone = 'Europe/Berlin'`.

Comment: But that is valid SQL for PostgreSQL. You can use `TO` instead of `=`, that is the same.

Comment: Actually, the `SET TIME ZONE` you did above is also valid SQL, sorry. How can you tell it shows UTC times? What exactly is the result?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply Laurenz, I have created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54480171/postgresql-sqlalchemy-and-timestamp-with-time-zone-why-is-incognito-different-f I found an other issue.